# How to calculate day from date object and if i is falling under weekend then increment it in java?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I have 4 dates i.e. today(current system date), activity date, quoteFinishFirstFolloupDate, and quoteFinishSecondFollowupDate which I have calculated based on some criteria but if that calculated date is falling on weekend (ie. Saturday, Sunday) then we need to increment or add days to it so that the next date will be weekday. So, how can I calculate days and add it so that it will be a weekday date? I have tried something but for Date object, I am not able to calculate the days.

Here is my piece of code:

```
if (logs != null && logs.size() > 0) {
  ActivityLog latestActivityLog = logs.get(0);
  Date activityDate = latestActivityLog.getActivityDate();

  Date today = new Date();
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(today);
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
  // check if it is Saturday(day=7) or Sunday(day=1)
  if ((dayOfWeek == 7)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
    today = cal.getTime();
  }else if ((dayOfWeek == 1)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
    today = cal.getTime();
  }else {
    today = cal.getTime();
  }

  // @TODO: @RD to check +1 day logic
  // plus 1 to include the endate=today+26 with time at 1pm
  Date quoteFinishFirstFolloupDate = DateUtils.addDays(activityDate, -1 * getUnboundQuoteFirstFollowupDays());


  Date quoteFinishSecondFollowupDate = DateUtils.addDays(quoteFinishFirstFolloupDate, getUnboundQuoteSecondFollowupDays());

  if (today.compareTo(quoteFinishFirstFolloupDate) == 0 || today.compareTo(quoteFinishSecondFollowupDate) == 0) {
    isValidCCVB_ActivityLog = Boolean.TRUE;
    log.info("isValidCCVB_ActivityLog:" + isValidCCVB_ActivityLog);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The major problem I can see is that you're using the outdated `Date` class. You should take a look at Date/Time API added in Java 8 (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime`,`LocalDateTime`), here is an [introduction tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro).

Comment: Use `c.add(Calendar.DATE, nDays); ` to increment the date. And why are you always adding `2`? If it's saturday OK, but if it's sunday?? And as Amongalen said, `Date` class is outdated.

Comment: I take it you mean date calculations involving working days only. What about public holidays?

Comment: I've seen people do this in the past by having a working calendar database table. You have 366 characters one per day. You can pre-generated it to exclude Sat/Sun easily - so those days would say have a zero in them. Working days have 1. Then you omit ad-hoc public holidays. Then you have a seed date, then say 5 working days later.. You count 5 ones into the array. You also have to read 2 records on year end... Or if your date span crosses multiple years, like say 400 days more...

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does your observed result differ from the expected? If so, how? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include …a specific problem …* From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank You all. But due to some restrictions, I am using date and Calender class.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Calendar c =
    GregorianCalendar                                                  // A subclass of `Calendar` legacy class.
    .from(                                                             // Convert from modern to legacy class. 
        myLegacyJavaUtilDate                                           // Legacy class representing a moment as seen in UTC.  
        .toInstant()                                                   // Convert this moment as seen in UTC from legacy class to modern class.
        .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )                           // See the same moment through the wall-clock date & time of a particular time zone. Returns an `ZonedDateTime`. 
        .toLocalDate()                                                 // Extract a date-only value.
        .with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame() )   // Move to the next weekday if not already a weekday.
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )                     // Determine the first moment of the day as seen in that zone on that date. Returns an `ZonedDateTime`. 
    )
;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the troubled legacy date-time classes such as both `Date` classes. If necessary to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* classes, write new logic in *java.time* and at the end convert to legacy objects.

## `java.time.Instant` is the new `java.util.Date`.

The `java.util.Date` class was replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Convert using new methods added to old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJUDate.toInstant() ;
```

## Date-only values: `LocalDate`

You said:

```java
  Date today = new Date();
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(today);
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Apparently you want to extract a date-only value from a `java.util.Date` object that contains a date & time-of-day as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. To extract a date properly, you must specify a time zone by which you want to interpret a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by time zone.

```
Instant instant = myJUDate.toInstant() ;    // A moment as seen in UTC.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;   // The same simultaneous moment, but as seen through a particular time zone. The time of day, and even the date, may differ from that of the `Instant` above.
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate() ;   // Extract a date only, discarding the time-of-day and the time zone.
```

Or more briefly:

```
LocalDate localDate =
    myJUDate
    .toInstant()
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )
    .toLocalDate()
;
```

Use that kind of code for 3 of your 4 `java.util.Date` inputs. For the current date, today, use this:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

## Moving between dates

You asked:

> if that calculated date is falling on weekend (ie. Saturday, Sunday) then we need to increment or add days to it so that the next date will be weekday.

This is surprisingly easy in *java.time*.

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for moving from one date to another. The algorithm by which you want to jump between dates is defined in an implementation of that interface.

The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class provides several useful such implementations. But none of those bundled implementations jumps both Saturday and Sunday.

The third-party library [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) happens to provide an implementation of `TemporalAdjuster` which does just what you want, jump past both Saturday and Sunday. Add that library to your project. Then access the `TemporalAdjuster` object returned by a call to [`org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame()`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDayOrSame()). The “OrSame” means if the date is already a weekday, keep it, no need to move to another date.

```
TemporalAdjuster nextOrSameWeekdayAdjuster = org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame() ;
```

Put that adjuster to work on each of the dates you care about.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameWeekDayClosestToToday = today.with( nextOrSameWeekdayAdjuster ) ;
```

Notice that *java.time* uses immutable objects. Rather than alter (“mutate”) the original, a new object is returned with values based on the original.

## Obtain a moment from a date-only value

So we have some `LocalDate` objects adjusted to avoid weekends. But you asked for `java.util.Date` objects (apparently).

To get from a date-only value (`LocalDate`) to a moment, we must apply a time zone by which to determine the first moment of that day in that zone.

Do not assume a day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some time zones start at another time, such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfNextOrSameWeekDayClosestToToday = nextOrSameWeekDayClosestToToday.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Converting from modern to legacy class

You commented:

> But due to some restrictions, I am using date and Calender class.

As mentioned above, you should avoid the legacy date-time classes. They really are that troublesome.

But if you must have objects of the legacy classes to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

To convert, first extract a `java.time.Instant` from our `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object.

```
Instant instant = firstMomentOfNextOrSameWeekDayClosestToToday.toInstant() ;
```

Then convert from modern to legacy.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

If instead of a moment as seen in UTC (`java.util.Date`) you want a moment as seen in our particular time zone, convert from [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class which extends from [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( firstMomentOfNextOrSameWeekDayClosestToToday ) ;
```

Putting all this code together:

```
Calendar c =
    GregorianCalendar.from( 
        myJUDate
        .toInstant()
        .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )
        .toLocalDate()
        .with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame() ) 
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) 
    )
;
```